# JMeter, How to encrypt whole bodydata in HTTP Request Sampler?

Tags: jmeter

I'm using jmeter 5.0 to test my web application.How to encrypt the whole bodydata using AES before post ?

I've tried to do it with BeanShell PreProcessor,but it seems there is no method to reset the bodydata,what I found is how to print the bodydata.

```
log.info("test");

String bodydata = sampler.getArguments().toString();

log.info(bodydata);
```

I've aleardy known how to implement the AES funtion by importing a java calss.What I expect is resetting the bodydata of plaintext to encrypted text.

Answer (score 0):

Put in body data just a JMeter variable as `${encryptData}`

And in preprocessor set the variable with your encrypted value:

```
vars.put("encryptData", encryptData)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is [Arguments.removeAllArguments()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/Arguments.html#removeAllArguments--) function which clears the sampler body
2. You can add the new body via [Arguments.addArgument()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/Arguments.html#addArgument-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) function. Example code:

   ```
   sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments();
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("","your_encrypted_data_here","");
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);
   ```
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting mainly due to the fact that [Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black). So consider migrating to [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) on next available opportunity, the same code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Under your "HTTP Request" add an "User Defined Variables" (empty values), Make sure as well to key in ${inputJson} in the "Parameters" text field in the "BeanShell PreProcessor" Element.